# Do stronger Conjuration spells make weaker bodies stronger?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've noticed you can summon weak creatures like elk and wolves with any level of Conjuration Reanimation spell, and was thinking to myself "Surely, if it cost that much magika to cast revenant than that revenant wolf must be beast compared to a raised zombie one". Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 2):

as i remember, it doesn't. remember that reanimation spells have level req.? that's because you can only use high-level reanimation spells on higher level enemies, so so using a master reanimation spell on weak enemies that you can reanimate doesn't change their stats

Answer (score 0):

Like ken said certain spells have certain skill requirements and using a high-level spell on a weaker creature doesn't change anything it will just raise them from the dead.